# How to call a function inside the bootstrap from a model in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a function on the Bootstrap.php like:

```
function test() {
    echo "hello";
}
```

I want to call it from a model. I already know I can do it from a controller using `$this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->test();` but no clue on how to do it from a Model. Any help?

I know it's not the best to have that function on Bootstrap and it would be better to have it elsewhere, but this can't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Front Controller` from anywhere in the application using this   [zend.controller.front.methods.primary.getinstance](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.front.html#zend.controller.front.methods.primary.getinstance)

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
```

So I think this will give to the result

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();  
$front->getParam('bootstrap')->test();
```